# How to remove the text between two colons using regex in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

So I have a line like this:

```
text1:text2:text3
```

I want to make it like this:

```
text1:text3
```

How to do that using regex?

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ is capable of regex search & replace.
So if you are always expecting a single keyword between the two colons this could be as simple as this:

find: `:\w+:`

replace: `:`

Screenshot:

[image: Notepad++ regex search & replace]

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `:[^:\r\n]+(?=:)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
:           : a semicolon
[^:\r\n]+   : negative character class, any character that is not semicolon or linebreak
(?=:)       : lookahead, make sure we have a semicolon after
```

- *Check regular expression*